# Is the bundler faster if code-splitting is enabled?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, code-splitting

I normally program in react-native or use webpack. In big projects the bundle time can be pretty long. In react-native I have to try to check whether `react-native unbundle` makes the app faster indeed or not, but here is the question:

Is code-splitting suppose to speed up building time?

Comment: I am looking something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it can even slow down a bit, as on every build webpack has to figure out how to split up each bundle. However there are ways to speed it up a bit but thats typically requires additional configuring [for example with DDL webpack plugin](http://engineering.invisionapp.com/post/optimizing-webpack/).

If you are looking to speed up rebundling checkout also [this article](https://medium.com/ottofellercom/0-100-in-two-seconds-speed-up-webpack-465de691ed4a).

Comment: But, if code is splitted, it could theoretically just update a smaller part of the bundle or file, so it does not necessarily slow things down. Especially for rebundle. Do we have any further proof or benchmark to take a look?

Btw, nice reads. Sadly I am restrained to metro-bundler for the moment, where I lack a little bit of expertise, but they are great resources, definetely.

Comment: There is a way with weback and ddl plugin to avoid rebundling of vendor modules (described in the article above). You can speed up rebuilding with cache mechanisms for babel, eslint, CSS but in my experience webpack still on every rebuild has take into account every module in path, apply leaders and produce separate bundles as you declared them. However Nextjs somehow is able to rebuild only a part of app that you work on. But I believe this is not easy even for experienced users and probably requires lot of configuration. That's all I know for now.

Comment: I'll leave the question as unanswered then for the moment. I'll try to put this to empiric test on React Native and I will com back with more info, to avoid misreads on the topic. Thanks so much!